# Как создать exception и вызвать его в sql триггере?

Tags: mysql, sql, исключения, триггер

Нужно написать sql триггер, который выбрасывает EXCEPTION при update записи в таблице если один столбец в записи - NULL. Далее нужно обработать его в java. Как сделать триггер чтобы выбрасывал данный эксепшн?
Столбец number - номер телефона. Если он NULL то нужно выбросить эксепшн чтобы его потом отловить в java.
Как отловить я знаю, нужно только с SQL.

Comment: check constraint лучше повесить, если версия mysql позволяет.

Comment: До чего ж забавная ситуация... джава шлёт данные в MySQL, и потом ловит ошибку некорректности данных - что примечательно, некорректности тех данных, которые сама же и посылает... а сразу проверить не судьба, до отправки на сервер?

Comment: У меня ТЗ чтобы пользователь приложения, который не указал номер мобильного телефона, получал форму для его указания при каждом входе и не мог ее обойти. Для этого требуется триггер, который выбрасывает эксепшн если номера нет, так будет проще через трай кэтч отловить этот случай и вызвать соответствующую форму.

Comment: Суть то в том что это не из джавы посылается, а просто при регистрации пользователем не указан номер, то должно при каждом входе выбрасывать окно для ввода номера. check constraint тут не причем вообще. Обрабатывать это должен триггер.